Clarification on Azure Communication Gateway with WhatsApp Integration Pricing
I am considering using the Azure Communication Gateway with the WhatsApp Integration to create a chatbot, with the Microsoft Bot Framework, that provides customers with insights and news for free. However, I have some questions regarding the pricing:

I noticed that the Azure Communication Gateway costs 1,200 USD per
month for 999 users. Could you please clarify what "users" refers to
in this context? Does it mean 999 unique phone numbers or something
else?

If I have only one phone number communicating with the bot, would the cost still be 1,200 USD per month?

Are there any other potential costs associated with using this service that I should be aware of?


and if I use the WhatsApp integration will the bot have their own phone number, or how do I need to set this up?
